# How can I make a transparent div that has a non-transparent border?

Tags: css

i created a white div and gave it an opacity of 0.4 and then i gave it a black border. however because i made the div transparent, the border was also transparent. How can I make the border non transparent whilst keeping the div transparent?

CSS:

```
#box{
   background-color:white;
   opacity:0.4;
   width:600px;
   height:200px;
   border-radius:15px;
   border: 5px solid black;

}
```

Comment: You looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nnt25251325/Dnfqm/1/) ?

Comment: make only background color partially transparent: use  rgba(255,255,255,0.4) and drop opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another div that contains the current div. Remove the border property and the width and height properties on the `#box` and add it the other containing div. Make sure the containing div has a class instead of an id. An example:

```css
.entirebox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#box {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="entirebox">
  <div id="box">
    <p>The stuff that you originally had here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I added the containing div and named it `entirebox`. Notice how the containing div has a class, while the div you started off with still has an id.

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for the help. this worked. but now that this worked i bumped into another issue. i want to add text into the box but of course its also transparent and when i try adding it to the 'entireBox' div it just pushed the box div down

Comment: @Musty in that case, this method will not work. Instead, just keep the CSS code you had before, `#box{
   background-color:white;
   opacity:0.4;
   width:600px;
   height:200px;
   border-radius:15px;
   border: 5px solid black;

}` and change the background color to an RGBA. Then make it (255, 255, 255, 0.4).

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. one last thing. These two divs (box, entirebox) are both inside on div which is just text, but the text is stuck to the border. is there a way to make a gap?

Comment: @Musty Yeah. just add a `margin-left`, `margin-right`, `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, or even just `margin` property to the element (`p`, `h1`, etc.) and add a number. That way, you can move it around inside the box. Hope that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make part of an element one opacity and another part of that same element another opacity.

Here is a silly example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/85utzq4p/

Try using rgba() for background color instead - or wrap the element in something.

```
.box {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something that can work with solid color backgrounds and image backgrounds both you can create another parent and set it in this way:

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  }

div.child {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  opacity:0.3;
}

div.parent{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border: 4px solid black;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```